# Do clustered PCs act as one computer? or still as separate systems?

Tags: cluster

While this is mostly a curiosity question, I am looking into this in the future...

If I were to buy the systems and switch (and such) and clustered them with ubuntu server, would it act as one PC with all the hardware together? or just separate.

For instance, If I were to install a desktop environment on the Main machine and look at the specs, would the cpu cores, ram, and disks add up? Or would these systems still act independent with there own hardware.

also, when these systems are connected through the switch, can more than one port be used if the system has more than on gigabit port?

I am asking this as I am already building on a small rack anyway and I am already building a system to render and as file storage.

stupid question, I know.

Comment: Pedia is your best friend if you want to learn about computer clusters   ----    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_cluster

Answer (score 0):

Clustered systems act as a single server for most applications. Whether the application is available on a single server with failover to another in the cluster depends heavily on the remaining setup of the application and storage, and is a complex set of questions. If the application is compatible with a cluster environment, the storage is shared by the cluster and the application processed do not require specific server identification, generally the cluster acts as a single system.

Comment: So, if a desktop environment was installed to the master server, I would, for example, see all the cpu cores and ram in total as one system?

Comment: No, they would still be different systems and that would be visible when looking at available resources.

Answer (score 0):

They act as separate machines that have a high speed interconnect and typically run one specialized application designed to take advantage of that interconnect to act more or less as if it were one big machine, for the purposes of that application.  For instance, a web server might appear to clients to be a single web server, but if you were to ssh into one of the machines, no, it would not look like a single unified machine with lots of cores.  It is more like they are running identical copies of the web server so any one machine can handle a web request the same way, and a router sends incoming requests to different machines to balance the load.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. Would an application be able to utilize resources across multiple machines? For example- rendering?